# Caffe negative training iteration loss

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network, loss, softmax

I have been trying to run a multi-modal cnn on the vqa (visual question answering) dataset. But strangely the training loss becomes immediately zero then goes negative. After shuffling my data the training loss does not immediately become 0, but still goes negative instantly.

To sort of debug this, I one by one commented all the layers to just have the basic imagenet layers, (so basically finetuning on vqa) but still the same thing as shown below.

```
I0415 21:17:46.399898 36477 solver.cpp:222] Solving vqanet
I0415 21:17:46.399953 36477 solver.cpp:223] Learning Rate Policy: step
I0415 21:17:46.399971 36477 solver.cpp:266] Iteration 0, Testing net (#0)
I0415 21:17:59.448454 36477 solver.cpp:315]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.135937
I0415 21:18:00.333122 36477 solver.cpp:189] Iteration 0, loss = 12.3874
I0415 21:18:00.333199 36477 solver.cpp:470] Iteration 0, lr = 0.001
I0415 21:18:27.789655 36477 solver.cpp:189] Iteration 20, loss = -83.2426
I0415 21:18:27.789788 36477 solver.cpp:470] Iteration 20, lr = 0.001
I0415 21:18:55.442523 36477 solver.cpp:189] Iteration 40, loss = -80.5134
I0415 21:18:55.442590 36477 solver.cpp:470] Iteration 40, lr = 0.001
I0415 21:19:23.450259 36477 solver.cpp:189] Iteration 60, loss = -327.512
I0415 21:19:23.450497 36477 solver.cpp:470] Iteration 60, lr = 0.001
I0415 21:19:47.745419 36477 solver.cpp:189] Iteration 80, loss = -416.213
I0415 21:19:47.745482 36477 solver.cpp:470] Iteration 80, lr = 0.001
I0415 21:20:14.822706 36477 solver.cpp:189] Iteration 100, loss = -563.594
I0415 21:20:14.822989 36477 solver.cpp:470] Iteration 100, lr = 0.001
```

I also ran the flickr_style_finetune model to see that whether softmax layer was correct, but there it worked fine.
Please help me understand this issue and correctly train the cnn.
Here is my  [train_val.prototxt](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=17025674319865089819) file.

Comment: Can you share your prototxt files?

Comment: sure .. let me edit the question

Comment: @HarshWardhan can you see the prototxt now?

Comment: In your loss layer there is not ``top`` instead,  there needs to be a ``top: "loss"``.